# What is i-amp-sizer and why some amp-img's show below this sizer?

Tags: amp-html

When I add amp-img, there is something like i-amp-sizer. My problem is, that i have some images that I want to get AMPed, and some of them didn't match this sizer (image shows precisely below the sizer).

Any ideas what can be the reason? I'd actually like to know what for is this amp-sizer responsible.

Comment: As stated on this [documentation](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-html-layout.md), any elements prefixed with `i-amp-` are considered to be internal to AMP and their use in user stylesheets is not allowed. They are shown here simply for informational purposes. You can check on this [tutorial](http://masup.net/2015/10/fits-amp-html.shtml). You can see in the documentation above that the value of the CSS "display" is `block` and its size id based on parent container and aspect ratio of `width:height`.

Comment: Thanks, make it as a post instead of as a comment and it will be accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated on this [documentation](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-html-layout.md), any elements prefixed with `i-amp-` are considered to be internal to AMP and their use in user stylesheets is not allowed. They are shown here simply for informational purposes. You can check on this [tutorial](http://masup.net/2015/10/fits-amp-html.shtml). You can see in the documentation above that the value of the CSS "display" is `block` and its size id based on parent container and aspect ratio of `width:height`.